# Debian - top(1) in batch mode, but sorted by PID

Tags: linux, debian, monitoring, top

I want to run top is batch / non-interactive mode with `-b`. However I want the output sorted by PID. What command line option does this? I'm using Debian Lenny and the `-o pid` option from here ( http://www.unixtop.org/man.shtml ) doesn't work.

Comment: On my local Ubuntu system, this appears to be default behavior.  I ran `top -b -n1` and it was sorted by ascending pid.  I also do not seem to have the `-o` option.

Comment: My systems (Debian, Ubuntu, and RHEL) sort by PID by default as well.  Are you sure you don't have a config file (/etc/toprc or ~/.toprc) changing the default?

Comment: That `man` page seems to document the BSD version of `top` rather than the GNU version. Since it mentions Linux, it would seem to imply that Linux versions support the `-o` option. Perhaps there is a Linux port of the BSD version.

Answer (score 4):

For me, on an Ubuntu system, with no `~/.toprc` or `/etc/toprc` running `top` 3.2.8, The primary sort is `%CPU` and the secondary sort is `PID`.

To set up `top` to sort by `PID` for batch mode:

If you don't have a `~/.toprc` to begin with:

- Start `top` in interactive mode.
- Press `W`. That will write a new `~/.toprc` with the current settings.
- Exit `top` (press `q`).

To create the necessary configuration files:

- Make a backup copy of your `~/.toprc` file. You will need this for a later step. Let's call this file `~/.toprc.ORIG` (you can choose another name if you prefer).
- Start `top` in interactive mode.
- Press `F`, then `a`, then Enter. That will select `PID` as the sort field.
- Press `R`. That will reverse the sort so it's ascending.
- Press `W`. That will write a new `~/.toprc` with the current settings.
- Exit `top` (press `q`).
- `mv ~/.toprc ~/toprc.PIDSORT` (or choose a name you prefer)
- Copy the backup back to the original (`cp ~/.toprc.ORIG ~/.toprc`).

To use the file you created to output `top -b -n1` sorted by `PID`, create a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp "$HOME/.toprc.PIDSORT" "$HOME/.toprc"
top -b -n1 > /path/to/outputfile
cp "$HOME/.toprc.ORIG" "$HOME/.toprc"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try running the output through sort e.g.

`top -b -n1 | sort -b -n`

That sorts the default output numerically and therefore by PID. It does though mangle the order of the header lines.